# "Undefined reference to dlopen" when statically linking with gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, static-linking, luajit

After reading up lots of gcc docomentation and similar questions my problem remains.
Im trying to statically link my libluajit.a into my project but no matter what combination of commands I try, one or another error pops up. Ive successfully compiled my project with dynamic linking though.
Right now Im out of ideas so heres what i got right now:

```
gcc_options = -std=c++11 -static -pthread

src_dir = LuaHost
src_files =  $(src_dir)/*.cpp
src_files += $(src_dir)/*.h
src_files += $(src_dir)/LuaSrc/*.h
src_files += $(src_dir)/LuaSrc/*.hpp

lib_cmd = -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -L./$(src_dir)/LuaSrc/ -lluajit

#compile everything and output an executeable
all:
    g++ $(gcc_options) $(src_files) $(lib_cmd) -o LuaJITSandbox.o
```

And heres some of the errors:

```
./LuaHost/LuaSrc/libluajit.a(lj_clib.o): In function `lj_clib_index':
lj_clib.c:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
./LuaHost/LuaSrc/libluajit.a(lj_clib.o): In function `lj_clib_load':
lj_clib.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lj_clib.c:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `dlerror'
lj_clib.c:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

The libluajit.a has been compiled on the same machine, a RaspberryPi.

Comment: Order of libraries when linking is important. If library A depends on library B, then A must come *before* B on the command-line.

Comment: add `-ldl` to the link command *after* the output, so try moving it to the end?

Comment: @Galik Nope, error remains unchanged. If messed with the order of my commands alot and that didnt change anything.

Comment: Actually scratch that. I think I missunderstood that at first, ive rearranged it as follows: 'g++ $(gcc_options) $(src_files) $(lib_cmd) -o LuaJITSandbox.o -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl'. Now it compiles but gives me a "using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications ..." warning. Can I ignore this?

Comment: There are 3 ways of dealing with external code: _static linking_ (_"copy" existing code, where needed_ - what you're attempting, which - excepting some cases - is outdated), _dynamic linking_ (via _shared objects_, reusing existing code), and _dynamically using shared code at runtime_ (via `dlopen`/`dlsym`, that you're also using - which is kind of unusual). [Here](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/877929-lnk-error-using-dlopen-statically-linked-apps-requires-runtime-shared-lib) is described a potential problem that _static linkers_ should be aware of.

Comment: "Can I ignore this?" - dlopen in statically linked application is generally not recommended. It's more of a hack and it is likely to [crash](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13470) when run on different system.

Comment: Try this: `lib_cmd = ./$(src_dir)/LuaSrc/libluajit.a -ldl`

Answer (score 2):

I think `-static` is not what you are after. `-static` will build a `static application` and does *not* mean `link this static library to the application`.

There are a few options here. When you link with `-lluajit` you could remove the the dynamic `.so` version of the library. gcc will default to dynamic linking, but will fallback to static linking when the dynamic library is not available or not found.

Instead of `-lluajit` you could just point to the static library file directly - treating it as an object input file: `/usr/lib/libluajit.a`.

I think the recommend way is to tell the linker how to link you library. Try using `-Wl,-Bstatic -lluajit`. You can switch between `Bstatic`and `Bdynamic` right in front of the library name in case you link to multiple libraries and want to link them differently.